# How to wrap img with text in email?

Tags: html, email

it's my first time with html in email, and I have to wrap image with text. I tried with align:left, but that doesn't work. Please help!

```
<td>
<img src="myImg.png" align="right" style="width:300px; float:right;">
<h5>bla bla bla</h5>
</td>
```

Comment: the easiest is to use table model for html in emails for compatibility reasons

Comment: yeah, i know, but it isn't an email for me

Comment: what you mean by not for me? what I am saying is that you should uae tables instead of float for html to be aend by email